# Is it possible to know if function uses empty return statement?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to know if a function uses an empty return statement versus simply not using the return keyword?

For example:

```
function noReturn(){ }
function useReturn(){ return; }

console.log( noReturn() );   // undefined
console.log( useReturn() );  // undefined
```

I know all about WHEN and WHY one would use an empty return statement, I just want to know if you can tell if `return;` was used at all versus no return statement.

I'm assuming that its not possible, and thats ok. If there was any cool Function prototype trick I didn't know of, that would be sweet.

---

Edit: Not trying to solve any particular problem, unless general curiosity is a problem. :)

Comment: From the outside and without looking at code or hacky stuff like stringifying and parsing the function? No. There's no way to tell.

Comment: There is no way to tell as `return` is the same as `return undefined` which is the same as no return (JS will return undefined), check the accepted answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337064/does-every-javascript-function-have-to-return-a-value

Comment: I'd recommend specifying a language in your question title and text... Not just as a tag.  That said, I don't think so...

Comment: @openwonk: Tag info shouldn't go in the title.

Comment: Whatever problem you (think you) are trying to solve, (most likely) you don't need to solve it like this.

Comment: @squint Thanks, added 
EDIT: removed it.

Comment: @SamEaton: *Shouldn't*. :-)

Comment: I'm bet you're trying to check if a function exited because of a particular condition check or if it ran "to the end". In which case you are running error handling and exception handling the wrong way.

Comment: I'm not try to solve any problem the wrong way. I'm literally just curious.

Comment: Alright then, I'm all for curiosity on the side of syntax boundaries and reflection capabilities.

Comment: The answer is, for all practical purposes, **no**.  Move on to the next curiosity. This one is literally a waste of time, since it explicitly doesn't matter whether a function has an empty `return` or no `return`.

Comment: One approach is to replace every valid return statement with another return statement that only returns a string. If there is no return statement, or logic flows into function termination, then 'undefined' is seen. Otherwise, the exact return is seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot distinguish return values of these three functions:

```
function a() { }
function b() { return; }
function c() { return undefined; }
```

according to JS specification.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a toy problem, but here is a possible *approach* to this problem. Convert the function to a string, then for all instances of a valid return statement anywhere in the string replace them with confederate return statements. Execute this modified function using `eval()` and observe what is returned.

For example,

```
function foo(){ return; }
function bar(){ if(0) return; }
```

becomes

```
function foo(){ return 'return;'; }         // "return;"
function bar(){ if(0) return 'return'; }    // undefined
```

This way whatever path the logic follows in the function, if *something* is explicitly returned, we can know what form it takes. If nothing is returned, due to design or logic flow, then 'undefined' is returned. Consider the following function:

```
function inspectReturn(fcn) {
  var str = fcn.toString();

  // Anytime we see a 'return something' we replace it with return 'something'
  str = str.replace(/(\b)return \s*(\S[^\n;}]+)/mg, "$1return '$2'");

  // Anywhere we see a lone 'return' we replace it with return 'return'
  str = str.replace(/(\b)return\s*([\n;}])/mg, "$1return 'return;'$2");

  eval("fcn="+str);
  return fcn();
}
```

We can then observe the return values from the the below sample functions:

```
function noReturn(){ }                     // undefined
function useReturn(){ return }             // "return;"
function useReturn2(){ return; }           // "return;"
function useReturn3(){ return true; }      // "true"
function useReturn4(){ if(0) return; }     // undefined
function useReturn5(){ return undefined }  // "undefined "
function useReturn6(){ var _return = " return "; return _return; }  // "_return"
```

**Demo:** [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/liruli/1/embed?js,console)

---

*Note:* Voice your opinion about how the regex can be improved all you wish. You might be able to break it (and congratulations to you), but there *are* simple and concrete JavaScript parsing rules for validating [return statements](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9), so on such a toy problem it's up to the reader to properly implement them. Also, if something is `thrown`, then `catch` blocks exist for that. However, this is a sufficient demo IMHO.

Comment: This I believe is happening to all, however the "OP" apparently wants if there is a way to do this without converting to strings.

Comment: That would be nice. However, since it's a toy problem, this is the path of least resistance.

Comment: @Drakes: It's the path of certain doom. It could fail in multiple ways. Only true way via the string value would be to create a JavaScript parser that can handle the function and everything that can go into one, which is pretty much everything.

Comment: Since it's a toy problem, how about native functions?

Comment: This really would be, but the right way would be: `(function useReturn(){ var _return = "return"; return f; }).toString().match(/return\s*(\w*);?\s*}\s*/)`

Comment: @wZVanG: I'm certain the examples in the question are just examples. He want's to know if it can be divined from any arbitrary function. That's really no closer to the right way.

Comment: The OP commented about this `This wouldn't work. What if the first function contains the string "return" and not the keyword . it would return true.` :P

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to differentiate these:

- `return undefined;`
- `return;`
- End of function without returning any value

First, both `return undefined;` and `return;` return the same:

> [**12.9 The `return` Statement**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9)
>
> *ReturnStatement* :
>
> - `return` `;`
> - `return` [no *LineTerminator* here] *Expression* `;`
>
> A `return` statement causes a function to cease execution and return a
>   value to the caller. If *Expression* is omitted, the return value is
>   **undefined**. Otherwise, the return value is the value of *Expression*.
>
> A *ReturnStatement* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. If the *Expression* is not present, return (*return*, *undefined*, *empty*).
> 2. Let *exprRef* be the result of evaluating *Expression*.
> 3. Return (*return*, GetValue(*exprRef*), *empty*).

And then, it does not matter if you used `return;` or nothing, because `[[Call]]` will return `undefined`:

> [**13.2.1 [[Call]]**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.1)
>
> 4. If *result*.type is *throw* then throw *result*.value.
> 5. If *result*.type is *return* then return *result*.value.
> 6. Otherwise *result*.type must be *normal*. Return **undefined**.

Answer (score 0):

Quite apart from knowing that JavaScript does not differentiate these. A way for checking might be:

```js
function noReturn(){ }
function useReturn(){ return; }
function foo(){ 
  var _return = "return";
}
function fooReturn(){ 
  var _return = "return";
  return _return; 
}
function fooReturn2(){ 
  var _return = "return";
  return; 
}


console.log(/return\s*(\w*);?\s*}\s*/.test(noReturn.toString())); //false
console.log(/return\s*(\w*);?\s*}\s*/.test(useReturn.toString())); //true

console.log(/return\s*(\w*);?\s*}\s*/.test(foo.toString())); //false
console.log(/return\s*(\w*);?\s*}\s*/.test(fooReturn.toString())); //true
console.log(/return\s*(\w*);?\s*}\s*/.test(fooReturn2.toString())); //true
```

Comment: Try `function(){ if(false) return; }`. The `return` statement will never be reached, but I don't think you can detect that with regex.

Comment: @Oriol It returns true

Comment: Think it through for a moment.